# Follow-up: Number of points on an elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, pairings, elliptic-curve-generation

Consider [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/100954/number-of-points-on-an-elliptic-curve#100958).

Say I would want to do something similar for $E_2:y^2=x^3−x+1$ over $\mathbb{F}_{3^m}$. How would I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Theorem 6.1 on page 11 of an [Introduction to Pairing-Based Cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_complex_plane), with $q=3$ we first consider the curve over $\mathbb F_3$. By exhausting over possible values of $x$ we quickly find that $\#E_2(\mathbb F_3)=7$ (specifically the points are $\mathcal O$, $(0,1)$, $(0,2)$, $(1,1)$, $(1,2)$, $(2,1)$, and $(2,2)$). This tells us that the value $t=q+1-\#E_2(\mathbb F_3)=3+1-7=-3$.

We then form the equation $x^2+3x+3$ and compute its complex roots $\alpha=(-3-i\sqrt{3})/2$ and $\beta=(-3+i\sqrt{3})/2$ and deduce that
$$\#E_2(\mathbb F_{3^m})=3^m+1-\left(\frac{-3-i\sqrt3}2\right)^m-\left(\frac{-3+i\sqrt3}2\right)^m.$$

We may now write the roots in modulus-argument form so that
$$\alpha=\sqrt 3\exp(i7\pi/6),\quad \beta=\sqrt 3\exp(-i7\pi/6)$$
so that
$$\left(\frac{-3-i\sqrt3}2\right)^m+\left(\frac{-3+i\sqrt3}2\right)^m=3^{m/2}2\cos(7m\pi/6).$$

Thus dividing into the 12 cases of the residue of $m\pmod {12}$ we have
$$\#E_2(\mathbb F_{3^m})=\begin{cases}3^m+1-2\sqrt{3^m}&m\equiv 0\pmod {12}\\
3^m+1+\sqrt{3^{m+1}}&m\equiv \pm1\pmod{12}\\
3^m+1-\sqrt{3^m}&m\equiv\pm2\pmod{12}\\
3^m+1&m\equiv\pm3\pmod{12}\\
3^m+1+\sqrt{3^m}&m\equiv\pm4\pmod{12}\\
3^m+1-\sqrt{3^{m+1}}&m\equiv \pm5\pmod{12}\\
3^m+1+2\sqrt{3^m}&m\equiv 6\pmod{12}\end{cases}$$