# Follow-up II: Number of points on an elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, pairings, elliptic-curve-generation

Context: [paper on pairing based cryptography](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Eajmeneze/publications/pairings.pdf), [question 1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/100954/number-of-points-on-an-elliptic-curve#100958), [question 2](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/101110/follow-up-number-of-points-on-an-elliptic-curve).

Let $E: y^2 = x^3+x$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ where $q=3^m$ for some $m\geq 1$.
Then I know that
$$
\# E(\mathbb{F}_{q}) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}q+1 - 2\sqrt{q} & m\equiv 0 \mod 4\\ 
        q+1 &m\equiv \pm1 \mod 4\\ 
        q+1 + 2\sqrt{q} & m\equiv 2\mod 4
    \end{array}
    \right.
$$

From this how can I determine the embedding degree of the curve?  I need to find $k\in \{1,2,3,4,6\}$ such that for a prime divisor $n$ of $\#E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ I have that $n\mid q^k-1$ but $n\nmid q^l-1$ for all $1\leq l< k$.

It obviously cannot be $k=1$, $k=2$, nor $k=3$. It cannot be $k=4$ either because $n\nmid q^2 -1$ and $n\nmid q^2+1$. But why is it then that $k=6$? (Other than arguing via elimination.)

Comment: Why do you exclude $k=1$? If m is odd, then q+1 and q-1 are both even, and then have $2$ as a common prime factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this curve has embedding degree 2 in the case $m\equiv\pm 1\pmod 4$ and 1 in the case $m\equiv 0,2\pmod 4$. For an embedding degree 6 curve you need to return to the curve of your [previous question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/101110/follow-up-number-of-points-on-an-elliptic-curve) and consider the cases $m\equiv\pm1,\pm5\pmod{12}$ where the point counts are $q+1\pm\sqrt{3q}$.

To understand these constructions the next step is to consider the factorisation of cyclotomic expressions. As polynomials over the integers we have the [following identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial#Fundamental_tools)
$$x-1=\phi_1(x)$$
$$x^2-1=\phi_1(x)\phi_2(x)$$
$$x^3-1=\phi_1(x)\phi_3(x)$$
$$x^4-1=\phi_1(x)\phi_2(x)\phi_4(x)$$
$$x^6-1=\phi_1(x)\phi_2(x)\phi_3(x)\phi_6(x)$$
where
$$\phi_1(x)=x-1$$
$$\phi_2(x)=x+1$$
$$\phi_3(x)=x^2+x+1$$
$$\phi_4(x)=x^2+1$$
$$\phi_6(x)=x^2-x+1.$$
These mean that if we want a prime $p$ such that $p|q^k-1$ but $p\not| q^\ell-1$ for smaller $\ell$, then we *must* have $p|\phi_k(q)$.

Now we also seem to be getting expression where $\sqrt q$ crops up, so it is worth checking out how these expression factor as polynomials in $\sqrt q$. The following may appear to be pulled out of a hat if you've worked with extension fields and splitting fields a great deal, but are easily verified from the high school formulae $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ and $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$:
$$\phi_3(q)=q^2+q+1=(q+1-\sqrt q)(q+1+\sqrt q)$$
$$\phi_4(q)=q^2+1=(q+1-\sqrt{2q})(q+1+\sqrt{2q})$$
$$\phi_6(q)=q^2-q+1=(q+1-\sqrt{3q})(q+1+\sqrt{3q}).$$

Now we notice that for the curve $y^2=x^3-x+1$ any prime that divide $\#E(\mathbb F_{3^m})$ in the case $m\equiv\pm1,\pm5\pmod{12}$ divides one of the brackets on the right hand side of the factorisation of $\phi_6(q)$ and hence divides $\phi_6(q)$ and hence divides $q^6-1$. This tells us that the embedding degree is at most 6. Now, we might worry that the prime also divides one of $q^5-1$, $q^4-1$,... $q-1$. However if $p|(q^5-1)$ and $p|(q^6-1)$ then $p|(q^6-q^5)$ and we quickly deduce that $p|q-1$. In the other case we see that $p$ would divide one of our cyclotomic polynomials and quickly conclude that either $p|q$ or $p=2$.

For the point counts in this question, we note that for $m\equiv 1\pmod2$ we have $q+1=\phi_2(q)$ so that the embedding degree is 2 unless $p=2$. For $m\equiv 0\pmod 2$ we note that
$$(q+1-2\sqrt q)(q+1+2\sqrt q)=q^2-2q+1=(q-1)^2$$
so that if $p|(q+1\pm2\sqrt q)$ then $p|q-1$ and so the embedding degree is 1.

Comment: But how would I determine the embedding degree for $E:y^2=x^3+x$ if $m$ is not odd?

Comment: It turns out that I had failed to spot an identity which I have now added to the end of the answer.